# C++ stringstream tellg()

Tags: c++, stringstream

I'm writing a little parser in c++98 (yup, cannot use 11).
I'm working with a std::stringstream which I pass by reference to different functions, let's call them subparsers.
In order to know which subparser to call i need to know the next word in the stringstream.
As stringstream is an istream it does have a peek function which returns the next character without moving the iterator / pointer / whatever it is that marks the current location within the stringstream, but as I need the next word I wrote a function peekWord
(ignore the commented line for now):

```
std::string Parser::peekWord(std::stringstream& sstream){
std::string myString = "EOF";
  if(!sstream.eof()){
    unsigned pos = sstream.tellg();
    sstream >> myString;
    //sstream.tellg();
    sstream.seekg(pos);
  }
  return myString;
}
```

which seems to work nicely.
While debugging I noticed, that as soon as i call tellg() after the pointer/marker/thing has been moved past the final word (which the returns -1), `seekg(xBeforeLastPosition)` doesn't work anymore and still sets the position to -1.

Does the call of `tellg()` at the end of a `stringstrea`m set that failbit or something like that? I would intuitively had hoped that the void function `tellg()` has no side effects.

Looking forward to hearing from you guys :)

pip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tellg` is specified as such:

> *Returns:* After constructing a sentry object, if `fail() != false`, returns `pos_type(-1)` to indicate failure. Otherwise, returns `rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, cur, in)`.

(`istream::sentry` objects are used to check that input is available.)

So, yes, it will set `failbit` on EOF. You can detect this however by checking `eof()` and using  `clear()` to return to normal processing.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, helps :)